# How can we write a different letters at runtime/ writing animation in unity?

Tags: c#, user-interface, animation, text, unity-game-engine

I'm making a game over panel and I want to write a "Game Over" text over the panel but I want to write this in a way that when we see it look like someone writing it on real time. What I have to do for this. I am new to unity please help me

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for the message to be typed in real-time or written (like with a pencil?)

Comment: Yes, you are right. I want the message to be typed in real-time or written (like with apencil). Is there a way that i can do this in unity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to draw it so it appears as though a person is literally writing it out (i.e. you see the individual pencil strokes for the lines of each letter), then you are out of luck.  That sort of thing cannot be done with Unity's animation tools.

If, however, you just want one letter to appear at a time, you could do something like the following:

```
public IEnumerator WriteText(string words) {
    Text textbox = gameObject.GetComponent<Text>();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach(char c in words) {
        sb.Append(c);
        textbox.text = sb.ToString();
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.25f);
    }
}
```

You would attach a script containing that to your `Text` object and call `WriteText("Game Over");` when you needed a game over.  Adjust the number in the `WaitForSeconds` constructor to speed it up or slow it down.

(Note: there could be a few small errors with names, etc. in my code; I'm not on a machine with Unity right now.  They should be pretty trivial to fix though.)